# Remove Object out of subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, subview

Hey guys I added a UIImageView to the subview and want to remove it after a couple of seconds.

```
        self.view.addSubview(car)
```

Now I want to remove the image completely. I tried something like:

```
        self.view.delete(car)
```

But than I get a really long error when I press the button, which should remove the image.
I hope you can help me out.

-Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeFromSuperview` is your way to go.

```
car.removeFromSuperview()
```

Methods to manage the view hierarchy are documented for [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview).